# Word Openxml: how to get a text box the right size?

Tags: textbox, ms-word, openxml, docx

I'm using PHP to generate docx documents from a database. The generated document contains column charts which have labels attached (i.e. user shapes containing textboxes). In an attempt to get the textboxes to accommodate and display all of the text (i.e. it shouldn't be necessary for the user to resize a textbox to see all the text) my code calculates how many characters will fit into 3cm, adds linefeeds to the string as required and tells me how many lines of text are needed. I have:

```
<a:xfrm xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
      <a:off x="1638276" y="1676399"/>
      <a:ext cx="1257325" cy="'.(252000 * $labelLeftLines).'"/>
 </a:xfrm>
```

which I believe should give me a text box around 3.5cm wide (extra .5 for the internal padding) and a height of .7cm multiplied by whatever is the value of $labelLeftLines. However, the text box always turns up as 3.cm wide by .86cm high, which only ever displays one line of text.
If I add in 'autofit':

```
<a:bodyPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" vertOverflow="clip" wrap="square" rtlCol="0">
     <a:spAutoFit/>
</a:bodyPr>
```

the generated file looks just the same, though, when I right click on the textbox to inspect the properties, 'autofit' is indeed applied. I have to uncheck it and recheck it to make it affect the textbox.
Any openXML gurus out there?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, some random floundering around revealed that the values I need to manipulate are here:

```
<cdr:relSizeAnchor xmlns:cdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing"> 
   <cdr:from>
     <cdr:x>0.47</cdr:x>
     <cdr:y>0.75</cdr:y>
   </cdr:from>
   <cdr:to>
     <cdr:x>0.67</cdr:x>
     <cdr:y>1</cdr:y>
   </cdr:to>
```

Changing those values does actually change the size of the texbox, though I haven't a clue what units are being used. From 0.75 to 1 produces a height of 1.43cm.
One day I'll maybe be able to find my way around the doucmentation.